# getting ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle12c

30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables error for below query:

```
MERGE INTO PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG ca1 USING PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG ca2 ON ( ca1.accrual_year = ca2.accrual_year 
AND ca1.accr_period = ca2.accr_period 
AND ca1.accrual_year1 = ca2.accrual_year1 
AND ca1.accr_period1 = ca2.accr_period1 
AND ca1.emplid = ca2.emplid 
AND ca1.project_id = ca2.project_id 
AND ca1.period_end_dt = ca2.period_end_dt 
AND ca1.report_due_date = ca2.report_due_date 
AND ca1.process_instance = '22187284')
WHEN MATCHED THEN   UPDATE
  SET CTS_ACC_REG_HRS        = STANDARD_HOURS,
    CTS_ACC_OT_HRS           = 0
  WHERE ca1.process_instance = '22187284'
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Looks like you're using the same table as source and target.

Comment: Yes, my source and target is same. i need to update the same table columns.

Comment: So every row is matched by definition. Why don't you just use a regular `update`?

Comment: You mean regular update with self join right?

Comment: Why do you need to join it to itself? Far as I can see, you only need a straight `update PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG SET .... WHERE ...`

Comment: Please correct if any wrong in below query.  UPDATE PS_CT_IQN_ACC_STG 
  SET CTS_ACCR_AMT_TOTAL = CTS_ACCR_BASE_RATE+CTS_ACCR_OT_RATE 
 WHERE ca1.process_instance = %ProcessInstance